# Dummy output (sound) in Ubuntu 20.04.5 after doing sudo apt update

Tags: linux, audio, ubuntu-20.04

My Dell Laptop came with preinstalled Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS. Everything was working fine for the last 3 months. I was using MS Teams Preview app for my office-related work. Both internal audio and microphone were working fine. Suddenly 3 days before my MSTeams output audio was not working so I had to use a microphone to talk with my colleagues. I thought maybe problem with the alsamixer, so I did some changes like increase and decrease in volume and all. It did not fix anything. So I did
`$ sudo apt update`

Some updates happened but still, output audio for MS Teams was not working. After i restart my laptop. When I did `$ alsamixer`

now it says: cannot open mixer: No such file or directory

When I went to check my sound in ubuntu settings. It's showing only dummy output as an output device. All options like internal-builtin audio, and microphone gone. Now I am really feeling helpless. I tried some of the article's suggestions from ask ubuntu and other platform like: [https://www.maketecheasier.com/fix-no-sound-issue-ubuntu/#:~:text=When%20experiencing%20sound%20issues%20on,see%20if%20it%27s%20paired%20correctly](https://www.maketecheasier.com/fix-no-sound-issue-ubuntu/#:%7E:text=When%20experiencing%20sound%20issues%20on,see%20if%20it%27s%20paired%20correctly)
but did not worked out.

A few important info about my ubuntu system:

```
$ lsb_release -a | grep Description
No LSB modules are available.
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
```

```
$ uname -a
Linux amit 5.14.0-1055-oem #62-Ubuntu SMP Wed Nov 30 04:54:03 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
$ sudo dmidecode -t 2 | grep "Manufacturer\|Product"
Manufacturer: Dell Inc.
    Product Name: 0C6CYC
```

```
$ lspci -v | grep Audio
0000:00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 51c8 (rev 01) (prog-if 80)
```

But when I do  `$ cat /proc/asound/cards` It says: -- no soundcards ---

```
$ alsa-info
ALSA Information Script v 0.4.64
--------------------------------

This script visits the following commands/files to collect diagnostic
information about your ALSA installation and sound related hardware.
  dmesg
  lspci
  aplay
  amixer
  alsactl
  /proc/asound/
  /sys/class/sound/
  ~/.asoundrc (etc.)
See '/usr/sbin/alsa-info --help' for command line options.
Newer version detected: 0.5.1
To view the ChangeLog, please visit http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-info.sh.changelog
ALSA-Info script has been downloaded /tmp/alsa-info.JX0noFz2n5.
Please, re-run it from new location.
```

When I try to list cards, it display nothing

```
$ pactl list cards
```

I am new to Linux. I will be really grateful for your suggestions. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your solutions. Unfortunately, none of them worked in my case, so I handled it differently. In every Ubuntu based linux OS, there is an in-built application called Startup Applications.

Step 1:
I opened the Startup Applications using the search bar.

Step 2:
I added a new startup program with the following details:

Name: Sound

Command: sudo modprobe snd-hda-intel

Step 3:
I restarted the computer.

Finally, it worked. Now, whenever I start the computer, this Startup Application runs and executes my sound command, so everything works as usual

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `sudo apt update` could not cause the issues, as this command does not update your packages themselves, but rather, the package source list with the latest repositories and updates. The error you mentioned sounds like Alsa is not installed, try `sudo apt install alsa-utils` (installs Alsa back), if that does not help, try running the Alsa Mixer with this command: `alsamixer -c 1`. The `-c` flag allows to select an audio card, and the parameter `1` is the number of the card. It's also worth noting that Alsa is not the audio server, but rather, the mixer. Ubuntu uses PulseAudio by default, try restarting the PulseAudio server with `pulseaudio -k`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried all the above suggestions like restarting of PulseAudio and installing alsa-utils. Even I tried ```sudo apt purge timidity-daemon```. But the problem remains the same. However I would like to mention that I have done ```sudo apt remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio```. And then I have installed again ```sudo apt install alsa-base pulseaudio linux-sound-base``` and ```sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop-mininal```
But none of them worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try this Command my issue was resolved : pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload